# Looking for a slideshow with delayed elements

Tags: looking-for-a-script, javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a slideshow script that's using a delay for the individual slide elements. Made preferably with jquery and with responsive webdesign in mind. It's easier to understand what i mean if you [look at Apples version here](http://www.apple.com/imac/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sequence](http://www.sequencejs.com/) has a demo specifically aping Apple's style, particularly the [iPhone 4s feature gallery](http://www.apple.com/iphone/). This one allows for arbitrary CSS animations(rotation, etc.)

[LayerSlider](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-the-parallax-effect-slider/922100) isn't free(though only $7) and focuses on parallax animation from top/bottom/right/left. There's also a [version](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-wp-the-wordpress-parallax-slider/1362246) integrated with WordPress(in case you use it) which can handle a bunch of the tedious animation configuration for you via UI; watch the tutorial video for details.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a pure html5 and css3 slideshow using a `<div>` with a series of child `<figure>` elements, each of which contains part of the 'delayed' transition - basically each 'slide' is a group of several images starting their transitions at different times.

There doesn't appear to be an exact slideshow that meets your needs [CCSlider (demo 4)](http://codecanyon.net/item/ccslider-jquery-3d-slideshow-plugin/full_screen_preview/162445) allows movable texts appearing a sliding over an image, [reveal.js](http://hakim.se/projects/reveal-js) also tilts towards some of these effects. [MooTools slideshow](http://ryanflorence.com/slideshow/) allows timed child elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control it with jQuery I would suggest jQuery Tools from flowplayer it's what I use.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html